.git-credentials order breaks git-push
EDIT: If it was a duplicate question I would have found it. This is a different way I get the problem, stop gatekeeping ffs, others need to find it too.
This is driving me nuts...
The ordering of the lines in .git-credentials breaks git-push, why is this happening?
https://user1:ghp_password1@github.com
https://user2:ghp_password2@github.com

When I change the order, it works fine...
How can I have two passwords stored, without needing to constantly switch the lines.

Do you use 2 usernames and passwords for 2 repositories? If so, try the config option git config --global credential.useHttpPath true.

Yes, I use them for separate repos. What does this command do?

Without the option as true, the first username and password is used for all URLs starting with https://github.com. Otherwise, it matches the whole URL to decide which username and password to use. Reference credential.useHttpPath.

This is so stupid... This should be the default. Please add the answer so I can accept.
